# Upgrade to IIS 7.5

Tags: iis

I have a windows server 2008 R2 based server with IIS 6.1 build 7600 installed. I want to upgrade to 7.5 but i don't know how.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 2):

This is just not possible. Windows 2008 R2 comes with IIS 7.5 and can't be changed/downgraded. 6.1 build 7600 is the version of Windows you have installed.

I'm assuming you are in the IIS Manager Help -> About IIS - look further down on the screen and it gives a detailed IIS version.

If you are in the IIS 6 manager, then it doesn't show an IIS version, just the Windows version.